# delete folder contents except a specified folder and its contents

Tags: linux, bash, cp, mv, rm

Per my other question, I have a script to update drupal core quickly and easily.

Presently, it moves the sites folder out of the directory, deletes the site folder's contents, then moves the sites folder back in.

```
mv ./sites ../sites
rm -rf *
cp -R /sources/drupal-7/* ./
mv ../sites ./sites
```

Given the fact that a sites folder can get fairly large, I would like to avoid moving it if at all possible, and delete only the other folders, leaving only the sites folder behind.

I have tried some other suggestions around the internet, a few from here, one of which used find, but that deleted the files and folders WITHIN the sites folder too.

I would also like to keep the source folder intact, i.e.: keep a sites folder within it for new sites, and move copy only other files/folders to the site to update like:

```
rm -rf * !sites/*
cp -R /sources/drupal-7/* ./ !sites/*
```

I have tried numerous methods, most of which simply don't work or give a syntax error (or delete sites or its contents)

EDIT: here is the script in its entirity, for clarity:

```
#/bin/bash
CWD=$(pwd)
cd $CWD
echo $CWD
if [[ $CWD = "/var/www/vhosts/"* ]]; then
    echo "Updating drupal core files"
    read -r -p "do you need to keep the .htaccess file? [y/N]" response

if [ $response = y ] 
then
    /usr/local/bin/drush vset maintenance_mode 1
    mv ./.htaccess ../.htaccess
    mv ./sites ../sites
    rm -rf *
    cp -R /sources/drupal-7/* ./
    cp -R /sources/drupal-7/.* ./
    mv ../sites ./sites
    mv ../.htaccess ./.htaccess
    chown -R httpd:httpd *
    /usr/local/bin/drush up && /usr/local/bin/drush updb
    /usr/local/bin/drush cc all && /usr/local/bin/drush cron
    /usr/local/bin/drush vset maintenance_mode 0

elif [ $response = n ] 
then
    /usr/local/bin/drush vset maintenance_mode 1
    mv ./sites ../sites
    rm -rf *
    cp -R /sources/drupal-7/* ./
    cp -R /sources/drupal-7/.* ./
    mv ../sites ./sites
    chown -R httpd:httpd *
    /usr/local/bin/drush up && /usr/local/bin/drush updb
    /usr/local/bin/drush cc all && /usr/local/bin/drush cron
    /usr/local/bin/drush vset maintenance_mode 0
else
    echo "Response must be either y or n"
fi

else
        echo "not in a web directory, exiting"
fi
```

Comment: If `..` is a different file system than `.`, then `mv ./sites ../sites` must copy all the files and remove the originals. However, if they're on the same system, it's a simple rename. Exploiting that fact, you could do something more like `mkdir tmp; mv * tmp; mv tmp/sites .; rm -rf tmp`... Although the `bash` `extglob` idea below is a good one as well...

Comment: ./ and ../ are the same drive, but a different folder. i havent tested the working script on a large sites folder yet to see how long it takes.

based on that, i may be wasting my time lol

Answer (score 3):

Updated as per suggestions in comments:

```
find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name "sites" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: You can first try with the find command only to verify that you are getting the correct directory list & then delete them with xargs

Comment: +1: though I would use `-I` option of `xargs` to handle directory with spaces.

Comment: Sorry, `-0` and use `print0` with `find`.

Comment: i should have added that the current directory, in this case, is one of a restricted patter established with help from @kevin:
`[[ $CWD = /var/www/vhosts/"* ]]` to make the script work in a number of vhosts. upon replacing `/path/to/dir` with `$CWD` it deleted the entire site folder (luckily it didnt move into the vhosts folder), and deleted everything in the sites folder too.

Comment: `rm -rf` is always risky and as I mentioned in the comment, its better  to check that only required directories are returned by find before piping them to xargs.

Comment: This find will include the /path/to/dir directory, which is not the intention.  Also, it will list all subfolder and subdirectories, which may be a very long list.  it would be better to add `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` to the find before the '!', which will force it only to find immediate children of /path/to/dir.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can enable extended globs (`shopt -s extglob`) and then use `!(sites)`:

```
bash-3.2$ shopt -s extglob
bash-3.2$ rm -r !(sites)

bash-3.2$ cp -R /sources/drupal-7/!(sites) .
```

Comment: i had tried to use the shopt -s extglob before, and i received:
-bash: !: event not found.

Comment: Run `shopt -s extglob` again just to be sure

Comment: And if it's in a script, you need to put it *in the script*, as it will not inherit it.

Comment: i added `shopt -s extglob` and `rm -r !(sites)` to the script, and i received this:
`syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: What system and bash version are you on?

Comment: the OS is Centos 6.5, bash is version 4.1.2