# Delete folder contents from Git history except for a set of files

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I wish to erase from the git history the contents of a folder (which can recursively have folders). However, some older commits don't even have the folder while some newer commits have files in that folder that I want to keep.

Let's say that folder is `foo` (in path `/path/to/foo`) and the files to keep are called `bar1` and `bar2` (e.g., `/path/to/foo/bar1`).

I realize this problem is not new. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098225/delete-folder-contents-except-a-specified-folder-and-its-contents), a long and hard-to-read (for a beginner at least) script is used. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834812/remove-all-except-certain-folders-from-git-history) is more up-to-date and uses `git filter-branch` but I didn't understand what the solution ended up being. Finally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633033/remove-history-for-everything-except-a-list-of-files-using-git-filter-branch) is probably the most similar but the answer is not "dissected" for someone with no advanced knowledge of git to understand, so it doesn't give me the confidence to try the commands out.

From what I saw, the current approach for git 2.17 is to use `git filter-branch` for each branch. Then use either a `tree-filter` or `index-filter` (from the documentation I'm not able to see the difference in use cases). Finally a `git rm` command with a regex that matches the contents of `foo` except `bar`. The first part of the regex would probably be simple (`/path/to/foo/*`) but I'm not sure how to add the exceptions.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could break this all down when presenting a command that solves this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
        dir=path/to/folder
        git rm -qr --cached --ignore-unmatch $dir
        git reset $GIT_COMMIT -- $dir/file1 $dir/file2 $dir/file3
'
```

The only difference between an index filter and a tree filter is, the tree filter loads the tree with all the content from the commit and then does your index updates for you by comparing all the content in the tree with what's listed in the index, updating the index to match the new tree content.  It's easy, it's just slow and usually needless.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer and explanation. Let me just check if I understood the rest of the command: first you delete all the contents from `$dir` and then reset the files that I want to keep, essentially bringing them back after also deleting them, from a commit called `$GIT_COMMIT` which I must substitute with a commit hash or HEAD. Also, this works for one branch at a time, so I must checkout each one and run the command per branch, correct?

Comment: No, you don't have to do the substitution, that's shell code, see the filter-branch docs.  You can do the entire history at once, add `-- --all` to the end of the args, after the last filter, see the filter-branch docs. The deletion is only of index entries, it's simplest to just clear out that one subtree then restore what you want but it couldn't get much cheaper no matter what you do, copying about 100 bytes per entry that needs restoring is going to be loads cheaper than running a complicated regex over every entry in the whole tree.

Comment: I see, the `filter-branch` command will automatically set the `$GIT_COMMIT` variable. From the docs, I should probably also add (before the `-- --all`) `--prune-empty` to remove empty commits and `--tag-name-filter cat` to update the tags.

Comment: Now you're getting it. That's the ticket.

Comment: Thanks! I promise this is the last question: after running the command and before pushing, how can I locally check if it worked?

Comment: The original branch tips are backed up in `refs/original`, you can `git diff refs/heads/master refs/original/refs/heads/master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208369/discussion-between-daniel-marques-and-jthill).